# Remove change from fork and sync to origin

Tags: git, github

I have made a change to my fork that was a mistake so now i want to reset my fork to that of the origin.   Note change was already pushed to GitHub.

```
C:\Development\IdentiyServer\IdentityServer4>git remote -v
fork    https://github.com/XXXXX/IdentityServer4.git (fetch)
fork    https://github.com/XXXXX/IdentityServer4.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.git (push)
```

As you can see I have two remotes set up origin is the main repo and fork is the fork on my GitHub account which i have access to push to.   I have to do pull requests from my fork to send them over to the main repo.

I did a pull on the main project to be sure it was to date

```
C:\Development\IdentiyServer\IdentityServer4>git pull origin dev
From https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4
 * branch              dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up to date.
```

I did the same on my fork

```
C:\Development\IdentiyServer\IdentityServer4>git pull fork dev
From https://github.com/XXXXX/IdentityServer4
 * branch              dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

I did a checkout on the dev branch

```
C:\Development\IdentiyServer\IdentityServer4>git checkout dev
Already on 'dev'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Which clearly shows that there are changes in my fork/dev that are not in origin/dev good these are the ones I want to remove.  I need to dump this change and get my fork back to the state of the origin.

reading this [syncing-a-fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) So i figured i should just merge in the origin/dev branch

```
C:\Development\IdentiyServer\IdentityServer4>git merge origin/dev
Already up to date.
```

I check the file and i can see that it hasn't been reset yet, and `git checkout dev` is still saying that its ahead of the origin.   I am thinking that somehow i need to roll back the last change but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset your branch to the upstream version:

```
git reset --merge origin/dev
```

This will discard all 5 of your changes.

Then push the result to your fork:

```
git push -f fork
```

Note that you must use `-f`, otherwise your push will fail, because normally the server does not allow to discard commits.

Comment: this seams to have done something similar **git reset --hard HEAD~1** but i think i like yours better.   and thanks for the -f tip!